# How do I use .NET 4.0 Beta 2 with Visual C# Express Edition 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-framework, c#

I want to play around with the System.Dynamic namespace using Visual C# 2008. I want to know whether its possible at all. Because, MSDN mentions that .NET 4.0 has some changes to CLR.

Do I need to install any other components to get it working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just download Visual C# 2010 Express Edition I have Visual Web Developer 2010 and 2008 on the same machine. You will still have the non-beta C# Express but can used C# Express 2010 to develop .NET 4.0 apps.
I don't think .NET 4 works in 2008 or earlier Visual Studios.